# Delete all links from quicklaunch?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to delete all the links in a quicklaunch in SP2010 with C#. I tought this will do it, but somehow they are not gonna deleted:

```
        SPNavigationNodeCollection n = subSite.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

        foreach (SPNavigationNode node in n)
        {
            node.Delete();
        }
```

Im able to add links, but not to delete them :/ Any ideas? Thx

Edit: Ah got the fix :)

I cannot write just `node.Delete()` I need to write `n.Delete(node)`

Edit2: hm somehow I dont get deleted ALL the links. If I run the code 2-3 Times then all of them are deleted, weird

Comment: What do you mean "not able to delete". Is an exception thrown? Do you get an error? Do they just stay in place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
 for(int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nodes[i].Delete();
            }
```

see this link also: http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/10/7/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-with-spnavigationnode-spna.html

Comment: Somehow your code is better, because its really deleting all of the links. And my foreach dont want to delete all of them in the first round. I dont get it, why? Its the same code just with foreach and I tought foreach is always better.

Comment: for more info check the url :
 http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/10/7/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-with-spnavigationnode-spna.html

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced this same problem myself.

I was able to delete the links on the quick launch by deleting from the bottom up.  My theory is that the collection is shifted up after deleting a link on the quick launch, so when link[0] gets deleted, link[1] becomes link[0]. Then when attempting to delete link[1], link[2] actually gets deleted.

Your problem is that at some point link[i] does not exist and error 'cannot complete this action' is thrown, yet you have not deleted all the links.

```
//Iterate from the bottom of the links to the top

for (i = numLinks-1; i >=0 ; i--)
{
    links[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to process the collection from last to first, because if you do it first to last as with foreach you're changing the collection when deleting items from it, messing up the iteration

Answer (score 1):

this should also work

```
 SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
 while (nodes.Count > 0)
 {
    nodes[0].Delete();
 }
```